# What datum (reference ellipsoid) does Nasa Worldwind use?

Tags: coordinate-system, datum, ellipsoid, worldwind

**What datum (reference ellipsoid) does Nasa Worldwind use?**

I can't seem to find where Nasa Worldwind tells explicitly what datum they use. I need some sort of valid link.

Comment: For what? The display? Or the reference system for the maps?

Answer (score -3):

It uses plate caree:
http://forum.worldwindcentral.com/showthread.php?t=10270
http://www.riacs.edu/research/projects/worldwind/extending/extending.jsp

Comment: plate carree <> datum. It's the map projection, not the earth model. The first link says WGS84; the 2nd link doesn't say.

Comment: I would prefer a more official confirmation rather than some random guy in the Nasa Worldwind forums.

Comment: agreed...not an ellipsoid